# Ugly error message thrown despite catch statement

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to catch the Number Format exception in my program.

I have a catch{} block for the same.

But even with it, the program throws the ugly error on the terminal and then the message in the catch block.

```
SPs-MacBook-Air:src sp$ java Calculator -10 *
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Calculator.java"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:15)
Error in expression1
```

I just want the error message to appear and not the ugly text above it. Can someone please help.

My code:

```
public class Calculator {

public Calculator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        char c = args[1].charAt(0);
        int r = 0 ;
        int x1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int x2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        switch (c)

        {

        case '+' : r = x1 + x2;

        System.out.println(args[0]+' '+args[1]+' '+args[2]+" = "+r);

        break;

        case '-' : r = x1 - x2;

        System.out.println(args[0]+' '+args[1]+' '+args[2]+" = "+r);

        break;

        case '*' : r = x1 * x2;

        System.out.println(args[0]+' '+args[1]+' '+args[2]+" = "+r);

        break;

        case '/' : 

        if (x2==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in expression");
            break;

        }

        r = x1 / x2;

        System.out.println(args[0]+' '+args[1]+' '+args[2]+" = "+r);

        break;

        default:

        System.out.println("Error in expression");





        }
    } 

    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

        System.out.println("Error in expression1");



    }










}
```

Comment: How does your catch block look?

Comment: Don't add code as a comment. Edit your OP and show the code there. Not JUST the catch statement... ALL the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `e.printStackTrace();` line from your catch block. That's the source of the "ugly error" you see.